# How can I insert into two sql related tables?

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables, one for storing person information and one for storing his phone numbers, tbl
-persons is connected to tbl_phones table using forgin key.

I have one form to insert into two tables and this is the function

```
 private void save()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_persons (name,address,fax,mobile,email,website) values (@name,@address,@fax,@mobile,@email,@website)" + "Select Scope_Identity()", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", T_name.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", T_address.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", T_fax.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", T_mobile.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", T_mobile.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@website", T_mobile.Text.Trim());

        int ID = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_phones (phone,person_id) values (@phone,@person)", conn);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", T_phone.Text.Trim());
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person", ID);

        int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int val2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (val > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("تم إدخال البيانات بنجاح"+ID, "تم", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign | MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
            resetFields();
            GetDate();
        }
    }
```

***but the error is that the person info is inserted twice and the phone number is inserted one one time, what is the error ?***

Answer (score 6):

You are executing the command in `cmd` twice. One is here:

```
int ID = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

And the other here:

```
int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Both instructions (`cmd.ExecuteScalar()` and `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`) run the command. Make sure you only have one of them (probably the first one, but you are the owner of your logic, so that's your call).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're executing `cmd` twice.

Once here:

```
                      \/
int ID = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                      /\
```

and once here:

```
           \/
int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           /\
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` twice!

```
int ID = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

And then ....

```
int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Hence, inserting 2 records

Comment: ExecuteScalar() is the same as ExecuteNonQuery();?

Comment: @amer Yes, ExcecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row returned in the result set. ExecuteNonQuery returns the # of rows affected by the SQL Command. So yes, in a way, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the first query twice:

```
int ID = Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

and

```
int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Remove the second one.

Comment: @amer Which line did you remove? you should have removed the second one, because If you remove the first one, you won't get the identity from persons.

Comment: @amer Also, I am not sure, but to be safe you need to add a ";" in your first query, like this: "@website);" + "Select"...